# What does "stagger" mean?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, terminology

In the **Heavy Armor** skill tree, the following perk exists:

> **Tower of Strength:** 50% less stagger when wearing only Heavy Armor.

What does "stagger" mean in this context?

Does it do anything if you already have the **Conditioning** perk?

> **Conditioning:** Heavy Armor weighs nothing and doesn't slow you down when worn.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may notice, from time to time, you or enemies will take a few steps back and not act for a few seconds: that's stagger. It's essentially a very short duration stun. *Tower of Strength* simply reduces the chance of getting staggered by 50%.

Stagger is not affected by *Conditioning*, which only affects the weight value of equipped heavy armor.

Comment: Some of the more common instances of stagger: blocking a power attack (staggers you); FUS RO DAH (staggers foes); Dragons landing (staggers nearby).

Comment: So it's definitely the *chance* of getting staggered, and not the duration?

Comment: @TM. As I understand it, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's definitely the chance.

With Tower of Strength + Fus meditation, my heavy armor character rarely staggers.

Note that this does not stop knockdown / knockback - so more powerful enemies like Duegar Deathlords will still send you flying.